# Using Unity DI container in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I'm new in WPF, and consider to try DI. I decide to take OnStartup method as Composition Root.

```
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {      
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMailSender, Model.Concrete.GmailSender>();
        var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

But, after the application is started, appears two windows, normal, with my content, and totally empty (seems like not initialized). What is wrong?

Comment: My guess is you have the Application.StartupUri propery set in App.xaml. You need to remove it.

Comment: If you are just starting, I would advise taking a look at [Prism](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism) which includes this DI functionality in the form of MEF or Unity, the real benefit of using an established framework is the amount of documentation out there. Other frameworks with similar functionality are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Remove the StartUri in App.XAML. Also it is good practice to set the application main window. Refer below code.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMailSender, Model.Concrete.GmailSender>();
        var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();            
        Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, `MainWindow` gets set to the first `Window` displayed automatically.